# Creating a BAT file to share multiple folders, and their sub-folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, share

I have a file server with multiple folders on it that need to be shared out.  Occasionally, the shares vanish, and need to be re-shared (beyond the scope of this question, I'm dealing with that as a separate issue).  For now, I am looking for a way to easily automate the re-sharing of folders via a single BAT file when this happens, so that I am not manually re-sharing several dozen folders by hand.

There are a limited number of specific top-level folders that need to be shared - Users, Jobs, Operations, etc. - this is not a problem so far, I can manually specify them with a NET SHARE command.

Where I am running into an issue is for a handful of folders that need *all* of their sub-folders also shared.  For example, every folder under D:\Shares\00_Users also needs to be shared as well.

I have a command that will share all files in the current directory, but not ones in another directory - meaning I need to leave a copy of the BAT in the share, which is not a good idea.  Is there a way I can automate this so that the BAT file will share each sub-folder in another folder?

Here is my current code:

```
NET SHARE "NameOfShare=D:\Shares" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
FOR /D %%G IN (D:\Shares\00_Users\*.*) DO NET SHARE "%%G=%%G" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
```

Where I am running into issues is the "%%G=%%G" - I want to replace the first part of the parameter with JUST the name of the folder, not the whole path.

Ideally this would share "D:\Shares\00_Users\JSmith" as a share named "JSmith"

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the basename & extension useable in `FOR` variables like this: `"%%G=%%~nG%%~xG"`

fixed code:

```
NET SHARE "NameOfShare=D:\Shares" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
FOR /D %%G IN (D:\Shares\00_Users\*.*) DO NET SHARE "%%~nG%%~xG=%%G" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
```

Comment: Bingo!  That was the key I needed, although the two parameters are reversed:

Comment: FOR /D %%G IN (D:\Shares\00_Users\*.*) DO NET SHARE "%%~nG%%~xG=%%G" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None

Comment: swapped. BTW Try to do `FOR /?` it's very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

With the help above, this is the final form of the working BAT file:

Full code used, as an example:

```
NET SHARE "D:\Business=Business" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
NET SHARE "D:\Engineering=Engineering" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
NET SHARE "D:\Jobs=Jobs" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
NET SHARE "D:\Operations=Operations" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
NET SHARE "D:\Sales=Sales" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
NET SHARE "D:\Service=Service" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
NET SHARE "D:\Scans=Scans" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
NET SHARE "D:\Users=Users" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None

FOR /D %%G IN (D:\Engineering\*.*) DO NET SHARE "%%~nG%%~xG=%%G" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
FOR /D %%G IN (D:\Operations\*.*) DO NET SHARE "%%~nG%%~xG=%%G" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
FOR /D %%G IN (D:\Sales\*.*) DO NET SHARE "%%~nG%%~xG=%%G" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
FOR /D %%G IN (D:\Users\*.*) DO NET SHARE "%%~nG%%~xG=%%G" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL /CACHE:None
```